# Docker won't expose my webpack port to my local machine

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack, docker-compose

I am trying to create a reactjs app with docker, so i need to expose my port 3000 which is the one of my webpack dev server.

Here is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:11-alpine

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
RUN npm i

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

`npm start` is just a `webpack-dev-server`

And my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'

services:
  sample-app:
    container_name: sample-app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
```

And when i go to `http://localhost:3000/` it dosen't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it with this :
https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/547#issuecomment-284737321

The host of the webpack config should be '0.0.0.0' and not 'localhost' (as it was in my case)

Answer (score 1):

In your docker file you need to expose port 3000. Add this to your Dockerfile right above the CMD line

`EXPOSE 3000`

The line in your docker-compose file maps the port 3000 from your host to port 3000 in your container, but without the line above, port 3000 is not "opened" to the host.

These articles provides additional detail: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/expose-vs-publish-docker-port-commands-explained-simply-434593dbc9a3

https://medium.com/@andyccs/webpack-and-docker-for-development-and-deployment-ae0e73243db4 (a little outdated, but some good info)